# Android RelativeLayout onclicklistener doesn't get fired

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

This is my XML layout - it's an info window.
i want that when the user clicks the @+id/fragment_info_relativelayout_content layout - the info window will be closed.

This is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_info_relativelayout_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_info_window"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <!-- The info textView -->

        <com.coapps.pico.NillanTextView
            android:id="@+id/fragment_info_textview_info"
            style="@style/text_shadow_black"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some Text "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:isBold="true" />
    </ScrollView>
    <!-- Tap to close -->

    <com.coapps.pico.NillanTextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_info_textview_tap_to_close"
        style="@style/text_shadow_black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/button_tap_to_close"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:isBold="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my code:

```
public InfoWindow(ViewGroup rootView)
{
    this.container = rootView;
    infoWindowView = LayoutInflater.from(rootView.getContext()).inflate(INFO_WINDOW_LAYOUT_ID, null);
    //find info window's view
    contentLayout = infoWindowView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_info_relativelayout_content);
    contentLayout.setClickable(true);
    contentLayout.setOnClickListener(this);     
}   

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
          //close the info window
    close();        
}
```

my problem is that the onClick method isn't being fired on every click on the layout...
it's weird since it does fire after clicking some clicks, or click at the bottom right on the textview...

any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, is that the `ScrollView` in the `RelativeLayout` handles all touch events, and don't let the `RelativeLayout` handle any touch events.

In this case, you should extend the `ScrollView` and make the `onTouchEvent` return `false`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

And the same to `onInterceptTouchEvent`

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

Just try it out and tell me what you got =)